# How to have submission page show total from previous form

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML named Week7.html, it results in a form like this https://gyazo.com/bd778ddcbb1a01374a37dd0605d13797

Comment: `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML ="Total Price: $"; + totalPrice` Right?

Comment: Yes, this should display the total price right? But when I test it, it doesn't display anything

Comment: Did you try exactly what was commented? Because there's a typo in there. I don't know if this actually is your problem, but it should be `= "Total Price: $" + totalPrice;` (semicolon was ending the statement before the price was added)

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript and DOM state gets lost when you submit the form (you're doing a regular submit, not an AJAX submit). Form submission triggers a new request, resulting in a new page. When the new page loads, you can only access whatever DOM is defined in that HTML file, from your JS. Since your processForm.html (by itself) does not have any form element called `orderForm`, none of the JS can work.

You could perhaps redesign this to do the calculation in the server and return the total alone in `processForm.html`.

Also, `<script type="text/javascript" src="processForm.html">` does not include the file. It needs to be a .js file.

Comment: So do I do this with two html files? This is for an assignment and we were given these two html files to work on. I need the second page (processForm.html) to display the total.

Comment: It will get rather ugly to do this with just your HTML files. Your JS in processForm.html expects the form structure from Week7.html. If you just want to display the total to the user (and have no persistence etc requirements), why not just do the calculation in Week7.html itself (i.e. move the JS from processForm.html there) and avoid form submission altogether.

Comment: The requirements are: -Form action set to “processForm.html”  -Alert is displayed when form submission is successful, with total cost of order -Order calculation is accurate (items plus shipping)

Comment: What if I moved all the JS from processForm to a javascript file called "calculations.js" then had this as me processForm.html code: https://gyazo.com/89a51b3c28198faf4b5066bff3dd7572

Comment: Still won't help. As I said, regardless of where the JS is included, it needs to "see" the `orderForm` form somehow, when it is loaded. In other words, you'll need to include it in a HTML file which has that form element as part of the DOM. This seems like a rather strange assignment, from the parts you've mentioned. I'll need to see the full thing to get more clarity. Also, are these HTMLs the same as what they gave, or have you modified them?